# How to handle tornado http_client.fetch in batch

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, asynchttpclient

```
def downloadTile(root, message):
  data = message
  tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure(None, max_clients=2000)
  http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
  http_client.fetch(data.url,  functools.partial(handle_request, root, message))


def handle_request(root, message, response):
  '''callback needed when a response arrive'''
  data = message
  dirpath = os.path.join(root, str(data.z), str(data.x))
  if not os.path.exists(dirpath):
  os.makedirs(dirpath)
  # filepath
  filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, '%s.png' % data.y)
    with open(filepath, "w") as f:
      f.write(str(response.body))
      log.debug("Downloading Progressing")
```

Fetch returns a future, and doesn't wait for the download to complete. With this code, we're actually sending every single request at almost the same time. That could be why downloading is failing for some tiles.

How to handle fetch in smaller batches or serially ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to not set `max_clients` so high. The default is 10; setting it to 2000 is excessive and inappropriate in most cases. Any requests in excess of the `max_client` limit will be queued up until another request finishes.

Comment: See https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/88eefe943461a354165db5398602d1185c6656b9/demos/webspider/webspider.py for a more complete example using queues for rate control.